# SOAP Android pullparser exception expected a quoted string

Tags: android, eclipse, soap, xmlpullparser

I am trying to get this http://www.apniurdu.com/Soap.html web service running on Android.

```
 private static final String cMETHOD_NAME = "Translate";
 private static final String cSOAP_ACTION = "http://apniurdu.com/SOAP/Urdu2.wsdl/Translate&quot";
 private static final String cNAMESPACE = "http://apniurdu.com/SOAP/Urdu2.wsdl";
 private static final String cURL = "http://apniurdu.com/SOAP/SOAP.pl";


 public SoapObject Translatesoap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request
        java.lang.String symbol="hello world, good morning";
        request.addProperty("symbol", symbol); //variable name, value. I got the variable name, from the wsdl file!
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //put all required data into a soap envelope
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request
        AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);  
        httpTransport.debug = true;  //this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent message was (httpTransport.requestDump)
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request
        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //get response
        return result;
     }

    try {
                        SoapObject result=Translatesoap(cMETHOD_NAME, cSOAP_ACTION, cNAMESPACE, cURL);
                //      Log.v("ergebnis", result.getProperty(1).toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.v("next", "try");
```

This is basically my code. 1st variables; 2nd the procedure, 3rd the calling of the procedure.
When running I am getting an XMLpullparser exception:

```
01-07 12:06:32.858: W/System.err(969): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.InputStreamReader@412d9088) 
01-07 12:06:32.858: W/System.err(969):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readQuotedId(KXmlParser.java:664)
01-07 12:06:32.868: W/System.err(969):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readExternalId(KXmlParser.java:643)
01-07 12:06:32.868: W/System.err(969):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readDoctype(KXmlParser.java:585)
01-07 12:06:32.868: W/System.err(969):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:418)
01-07 12:06:32.868: W/System.err(969):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
01-07 12:06:32.868: W/System.err(969):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2029)
01-07 12:06:32.878: W/System.err(969):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
01-07 12:06:32.878: W/System.err(969):  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
01-07 12:06:32.878: W/System.err(969):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
01-07 12:06:32.878: W/System.err(969):  at com.example.c_f_converter_ksoap2.ManuelleSOAP.Translatesoap(ManuelleSOAP.java:64)
01-07 12:06:32.889: W/System.err(969):  at com.example.c_f_converter_ksoap2.ManuelleSOAP$2.onClick(ManuelleSOAP.java:102)
01-07 12:06:32.889: W/System.err(969):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-07 12:06:32.898: W/System.err(969):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
01-07 12:06:32.898: W/System.err(969):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-07 12:06:32.898: W/System.err(969):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 12:06:32.898: W/System.err(969):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 12:06:32.908: W/System.err(969):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-07 12:06:32.908: W/System.err(969):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 12:06:32.918: W/System.err(969):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 12:06:32.927: W/System.err(969):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-07 12:06:32.927: W/System.err(969):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-07 12:06:32.927: W/System.err(969):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 12:06:32.927: V/next(969): try
```

in short: expected a quoted string at parse response - as far as I know.
Any clues how to solve that? Many thanks in advance!

update:
i think i used the wrong URL.. now i changed the URL into the wsdl URL "http://apniurdu.com/SOAP/Urdu2.wsdl" and get an error "unexpected start token"

```
01-07 13:09:23.527: W/System.err(1149): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <definitions name='UrduSOAP' targetNamespace='http://apniurdu.com/SOAP/Urdu2.wsdl'>@10:43 in java.io.InputStreamReader@412dbf58)
```

so is the wsdl not compatible with ksoap2? or am I doing something wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is this line

```
private static final String cSOAP_ACTION = "http://apniurdu.com/SOAP/Urdu2.wsdl/Translate&quot";
```

maybe you have to remove the &quot, so you should write this:

```
private static final String cSOAP_ACTION = "http://apniurdu.com/SOAP/Urdu2.wsdl/Translate";
```

**EDIT**

It's not for the question, but for the OP, a little help to get started with ksoap2

```
public SoapObject testMethod(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE,   String URL, String parameter) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
    {
        List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("variablename", parameter);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        //envelope.dotNet = true; for .net services
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headers);

        return (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    }
```

So this is a basic call with ksoap2 and with a string parameter.

Comment: this did not work, i added the &quote later and forgot to remove it - however, i get another error now, see updated post please

Comment: I looked at the wsdl and maybe I have an idea. Use `private static final String cSOAP_ACTION = "http://apniurdu.com/SOAP/Urdu2.wsdl#Translate";`. I changed the '/' character to '#'. Please try this.

Comment: Hi, i have tryed that too, but with no success. Now i read in another stackoverflow post that the URL "Should point not to the wsdl, but to the php file" so I am really wondering now if  "AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);   " URL should point to the wsdl or to the "soap:address location="http://apniurdu.com/SOAP/SOAP.pl" "service location

Comment: Maybe the service is not functional. If you try to open it in the browser, it says:
Internal Server Error

Comment: you are probably right, i cannot even run the examples on their Website, Internal error..

Comment: yeah i will give you can upvote. Somehow i'm only getting into dead ends. I tryed another webservice now and im getting "org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT Bad Request@1:12 in java.io.InputStreamReader@412f5f78) " so while trying to solve one problem i got many more...

Comment: see my edit, I hope it helped you and if you've got a question, just ask